# How to fork a particular branch only from a GitHub repository?

Tags: github

If a repository has multiple branches, is it possible to fork a particular branch only as a main branch in my fork, on GitHub?

[image: a GitHub repository]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, as the [wiki](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) states:

> A fork is a copy of a repository.

So by definition, you cannot fork a branch.

Answer (score -2):

This question was asked over at StackOverflow.SE and got the following response:

[image]

Source: [Fork from a branch in github - StackOverflow.SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227873/fork-from-a-branch-in-github)

Comment: Did you really use an image of a Stack Overflow post? How is that useful? Blind users can't see that, for one thing, nor will search engines be able to index it. You should _quote_ the relevant portions and link to the source.

Comment: @AlE. I linked and flagged it. At the time I was unsure if quoting whole posts was an acceptable practice, though I did not want to simply post a link either.